# how build a nonlinear regression and find the error of approximation

Tags: r

There was a problem in constructing the approximation of the diode voltage-ampere characteristic(code below).

```
library(ggplot2)
chart <- ggplot() + geom_point(data =  mat,aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a*(exp(x/b) - 1)',
         method.args = list(start=c(a=0.1646, b=9.5e-8)),se=FALSE)
chart
```

`mat`:

```
mat <- structure(list(x = c(0, 0.25, 0.27, 0.29, 0.31, 0.33, 0.34, 0.36, 
0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.4, 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 
0.48, 0.49, 0.5, 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 
0.59, 0.6, 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68), y = c(4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 16L, 20L, 23L, 28L, 37L, 43L, 55L, 
67L, 81L, 94L, 118L, 143L, 187L, 225L, 272L, 340L, 430L, 510L, 
626L, 900L, 1020L, 1220L, 1640L, 1850L, 2360L, 2930L, 3570L, 
4290L, 5000L, 6570L, 7390L, 9230L, 9960L)), .Names = c("x", "y"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```

Approximation line is not being built !!! What is the problem? How to find the approximation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good evening :)

I usually put the `aes` and `data` in to the initial ggplot for these cases. When I did that, it threw a warning. I tried the `nls` stand alone and there is an error in there. I'd suggest investigating this, and see if resolving the problem resolves your plot issues. Code:

```
chart <- ggplot(data = mat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a*(exp(x/b) - 1)',
              method.args = list(start=c(a=0.1646, b=9.5e-8)),se=FALSE)
chart

nls('y~a*(exp(x/b) - 1)', mat, start=c(a=0.1646, b=9.5e-8))
```

Error thrown is:

```
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

Edit: Always check your starting points:

```
a=0.1646
b=9.5e-8
y <- a*(exp(mat$x/b) - 1)
y
plot(mat$x, y)
```

Transformation produces almost all infinites

I followed this link for style:
https://plot.ly/ggplot2/stat_smooth/

Cheers,
Jonny